# Model tree in forge viewer the in BIM360 viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have issue in forge viewer the same file in BIM360 all items separated in deferent nodes but in our app all items grouped in on node as below images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuTT6.png)

BIM360 Viewer:

Forge Viewer In my App

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYWCl.png)

Comment: What is your source model format is? RVT, IFC, RVT->NWC?

Comment: source model format RVT

Comment: But from your snapshot, it looks like NWC or NWD imported many Revit files. Anyway ... Since your information is limited, it's hard to tell what happened. Could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible model to `forge (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com` for investigations?